# Style react-bootstrap button from css

Tags: css, reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I am fairly new to React and JavaScript in general.

I am using Button from react-bootstrap from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/ but I want to style the Button on top of it in my React app from my css file but it does not seem to apply.

my Home.js file looks like

```
import React from "react";
import '../App.css'; // Reflects the directory structure

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <Button variant="light" className="formButtons">
    </div>
  )
}
```

My App.css file looks like

```
.formButtons {
  margin: 10;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  color: red;
}
```

I can tell it does not apply since the text color isn't red.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used your document inspector to see if that rule is there and overridden by something else? It's a bit hard to diagnose without a demo.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to import the Button element from *react-bootstrap*. You can write something like this:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

After that, you can remove the className attribute because React Bootstrap builds the component classNames in a consistent way that you can rely on. You can base your styles on the variant attribute, so try something like this:

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import '../App.css'; // Reflects the directory structure

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <Button variant="light">TEXT</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.css

```
.btn-light {
   margin: 10;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: My problem is that if I do <Button variant="light" style={{margin: 10}}> versus <Button variant="light"> with .btn-light { margin: 10px; } the .btn-light doesn't register the styling

Comment: @jimmyhuang0904 if you inspect the Button element which classes you see?

Comment: after using .btn-light it works! When I inspect the Button element I see both classes, but I think className properties I set in formButtons were being overridden somehow